# Oracle 11g r2 string aggregation

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table with ID and location columns and I'm trying to combine multiple rows into comma separated listed. 
For eg:

```
Source table:   ID    Location      Name
                 1        USA       Bob 
                 1        Brazil    Bob
                 1        Russia    Bob
                 2        India     Emily
                 2        China     Emily
```

My target table should get the values like this

```
Target table:   ID    Location             Name
                 1     USA, Brail, Russia  Bob
                 2     India, China        Emily
```

How can I Perform this using oracle 11g R2?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `listagg()`:

```
select id, listagg(location, ', ') within group (order by id) as location
from source
group by id
```

This does not guarantee the original ordering in the table.  SQL tables are inherently unordered, so to guarantee this, you would need a distinct row id for each row.  This following might get close:

```
select id, listagg(location, ', ') within group (order by seqnum) as location
from (select *, rownum as seqnum from source) s
group by id
```

Comment: Missing within keyword

Comment: I tried this select id, wm_concat(Location) as locations
from sourcetable
group by id and this seems to be working.

Comment: But my solutions is not working if I need to select extra columns from source.